# Sorting ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, comparable

I have a class (that implement Comparable) composed by:

```
double[1][2];
```

I would sorting my arrayList and i tried in this way but i reported an error:

```
public double compareTo(Matrix another) {
return this.getCell(0,1).compareTo(another.getCel(0,1));
}
```

How can sorting in this way?

Comment: What error? Where? What does `getCell` return? Btw you wrote it wrong the second time `getCel`.

Comment: `compareTo` should return an `int`

Comment: Why do you have a 1x2 array of doubles? Why not `double[2]`?

Comment: As andy256 said, `compareTo` should return an `int`, and that could be causing the problem. But also, your `getCell` method should return an `Integer` (wrapper class) and not an `int`. Since you haven't posted the error, it's impossible to say. Please post your error message next time.

Comment: getCell return double. How can compare double?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, the call to `getCell()` returns a `double`, which doesn't have methods (like (`compareTo()`).

Also, the `compareTo()` method of the `Compareae` interface must return `int`, not `double`.

Try this:

```
public int compareTo(Matrix another) {
    double diff = getCell(0,1) - another.getCel(0,1);
    return diff == 0 ? 0 : diff > 0 ? 1 : -1;
}
```

This solution will work in all java versions. For java 7+, you may do thus instead:

```
public int compareTo(Matrix another) {
    return Double.compare(getCell(0, 1), another.getCell(0, 1));
}
```

Also note the slight clean up of removing the redundant `this.` from your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear and it would help to post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). But since `getCell` returns `double`, your method should probably look like this:

```
public int compareTo(Matrix another) {
    return Double.valueOf(this.getCell(0, 1))
            .compareTo(Double.valueOf(another.getCell(0, 1)));
}
```

The way this works is to wrap each compared `double` primitive in a `Double` object. Since `Double` implements `Comparable<Double>`, your method can delegate to [`Double.compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compareTo%28java.lang.Double%29).

Alternatively, you could use the static utility method [`Double.compare(double, double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare%28double,%20double%29):

```
public int compareTo(Matrix another) {
    return Double.compare(this.getCell(0, 1), another.getCell(0, 1));
}
```

This is preferable because it's more concise, but I wanted to mention the first solution because it involves [*boxing*](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=197) primitives to their object counterparts, which is often necessary in general in order to take advantage of class methods and to use primitives in collections.